# Mean and Variance of an offspring

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

If I have that the number of offspring of an individual in a population is $0$, $1$, or $2$ with respective probabilities $a>0$, $b>0$ and $c>0$, where $a+b+c=1$, how would I express the mean and variance of the offspring of the distribution in terms of $b$ and $c$?

Comment: I am wondering why you have tagged this as a "process" question. Does the population evolve over time? In any case, can you include your own thoughts in your post? Perhaps give the formula that you think is appropriate.

Comment: What has me confused is in our book it says the mean of an offspring distribution is $M(n)=\mu$ and variance is $V(n)=\sigma^2$, so I don't know how I am supposed to get this in terms of a,b, and c

Comment: I believe you are supposed to calculate the mean from the information given. So if $n$ is the number of offspring, calculate $M(n)=0P(n=0)+1P(n=1)+2P(n=2)$.

Comment: Awesome.  I understand it way better now.  Thank you!